# ReadOnly="<%# Bind("ServerProp") %>" syntax error

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to bind a bool from the server to the markup:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="RevSharePercent" HeaderText="Revenue Share Percentage"
  SortExpression="RevSharePrecentage" ReadOnly="<%=SetFieldsReadOnly%>" />
```

but rendering shows the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Literal content ('<asp:BoundField
DataField="RevSharePercent" HeaderText="Revenue Share Percentage"
SortExpression="RevSharePrecentage" ReadOnly="') is not allowed within a
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.

Source Error: 
Line 59:<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E8E8E8" /> 
Line 60:    <Fields> 
Line 61:      <asp:BoundField DataField="RevSharePercent" HeaderText="Revenue Share Percentage" 
Line 62:        SortExpression="RevSharePrecentage" ReadOnly="<%# Bind("SetFieldsReadOnly") %>" /> 
Line 63:      <asp:BoundField DataField="ScreeningPercent" HeaderText="Screening Percentage" 
                SortExpression="ScreeningPercent" ReadOnly="<%# Bind("SetFieldsReadOnly") %>" />
```

**update**
Tried "<%#Bind("SetFieldsReadOnly") %>"
and ReadOnly="<%#Eval("SetFieldsReadOnly") %>" />
both didn't work

> Parser Error Message: Literal content ('
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 59:                          Line 60:                          Line
>   61:                             
>   SortExpression="RevSharePrecentage"
>   ReadOnly="<%#Bind("SetFieldsReadOnly") %>" /> Line 63:
>   " />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to try:

```
'<%# Bind("SetFieldsReadOnly") %>'
```

or

```
'<%# Eval("SetFieldsReadOnly") %>'
```

rather than

```
<%=SetFieldsReadOnly%>
```

note the Bind / Eval.

just found this information regarding syntax on another site

In ASP.NET 1.1 the databinding tags were:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, ''expression'' ) %>
<%# DataBinder.Eval( '', '', ''format string'') %>
```

ASP.NET 2.0 offer those as well as the following:

```
<%# Eval(''expression'') %>
<%# Eval(''expression'', ''format string'') %>
<%# Bind(''expression'') %>
<%# Bind(''expression'', ''format string'') %>
```

Comment: Have you got the space in between the # and Bind/Eval?

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are culprit. aspx parser thinks `ReadOnly=“<%# Bind("` is attibute declaration and value, and got confused with rest of strings. It expects `space` after attribute values. Change it to `ReadOnly='<%# Bind("ServerProp") %>'`

Comment: ServerPro should be `bool` or `string`?